# Liferay search user by phone number

Tags: search, indexing, liferay

I'm new to Liferay and working on the Liferay search. I have found that i can't search users when i search on telephone number. i have looked around but i coundn't find a answer anywhere. Could you guys help me how i could solve this.

I tried a [tutorial](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/extending-the-indexer-post-processor-using-a-hook) to search on job title.

That worked but i coun't get Phone number to work. I'm working with Liferay 6.4.

Comment: So i want to add phone number search in the search portlet. i have found out that phone number is not index in the searchindex. I don't know so mutch about Liferay but i espect that i have to index the phone numbers almost simular to the Job Title. But i can't findt how to do that

Comment: How to get user's phones: http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/105992

Comment: Ty for helping me so far. That is phone number by userid. I want to put the Phone number in the searchbar and get back the list of users with that phone number. That is a question that i haven't seen.

Comment: Well, you need to index the phone numbers and then use them in query. Regrettably, I don't know how to do it with the default search engine (Lucene). But if you used Solr engine, I could give you few hints, as I've already implemented similar functionality.

Comment: I have implemented Elasticsearch with liferay with the ElasticRay plug-in. But can't it be done like the Job Title? the Phone numbers are already in Liferay but it can't be searched.

Comment: As you can see in the tutorial, the `SampleIndexPostProcessor` replaces the *existing* index field `Field.TITLE` with the content of the user's `jobTitle` attribute. But (IMHO) you cannot use that for phones, as there can be more than one phone. So you have to define your custom field, add the phone numbers into the field, and then adjust the query to use the field.

Answer (score 0):

Following the above discussion, I am pasting a bit of our code for inspiration.

We had a similar requirement: to allow search within user's areas of interest / areas of expertise, which is a custom data structure (sort of tags), i.e. not indexed by default.

First, I defined new `text` fields in Solr's `scheme.xml` - their names are stored in constants `AREAS_OF_EXPERTISE` and `AREAS_OF_INTEREST`.

Then, we've written our custom `IndexerPostProcessor` and overriden the `postProcessDocument` and `postProcessSearchQuery` methods:

```
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.search.BaseIndexerPostProcessor;
// other imports

public class CustomUserIndexerPostProcessor extends BaseIndexerPostProcessor implements CustomeIndexerConstants {

    private static Log log = LogFactoryUtil.getLog(CustomUserIndexerPostProcessor.class);    

    @Override
    public void postProcessSearchQuery(BooleanQuery searchQuery, SearchContext searchContext) throws Exception {
        searchQuery.addTerm(AREAS_OF_EXPERTISE, searchContext.getKeywords());
        searchQuery.addTerm(AREAS_OF_INTEREST, searchContext.getKeywords());
    }

    @Override
    public void postProcessDocument(Document document, Object obj) throws Exception {
        addAreasOfExpertise(document);
        addAreasOfInterest(document);
    }

    private void addAreasOfExpertise(Document document) throws NestableException  {
        long userID = GetterUtil.getLong(document.get(Field.ENTRY_CLASS_PK));
        AssetEntry expertiseEntry = AssetEntryLocalServiceUtil.fetchEntry(User.class.getName() + "#areasOfExpertise", userID);
        String[] expertiseTags = new String[] {};
        if (expertiseEntry != null) {
            expertiseTags = expertiseEntry.getTagNames();
        }
        log.debug("Adding areas of expertise to user [" + document.get("fullName") + "]: " + StringUtil.merge(expertiseTags));
        document.addText(AREAS_OF_EXPERTISE, StringUtil.merge(expertiseTags, ", "));
    }

    private void addAreasOfInterest(Document document) throws NestableException {
        long userID = GetterUtil.getLong(document.get(Field.ENTRY_CLASS_PK));
        AssetEntry interestsEntry = AssetEntryLocalServiceUtil.fetchEntry(User.class.getName() + "#areasOfInterest", userID);
        String[] interestsTags = new String[] {};
        if (interestsEntry != null) {
            interestsTags = interestsEntry.getTagNames();
        }
        log.debug("Adding areas of interest to user [" + document.get("fullName") + "]: " + StringUtil.merge(interestsTags));
        document.addText(AREAS_OF_INTEREST, StringUtil.merge(interestsTags, ", "));
    }

}
```

And the last step is to add this custopm postprocessor class into your `liferay-hook.xml`:

```
<indexer-post-processor>
    <indexer-class-name>com.liferay.portal.model.User</indexer-class-name>
    <indexer-post-processor-impl>our.company.projectname.search.CustomUserIndexerPostProcessor</indexer-post-processor-impl>
</indexer-post-processor>
```

And you are ready to deploy. Of course, you have to reindex the whole portal content after deploying this change (as described in the step #5 of the tutorial).